# Splitting a semicolon-separated with equal in a string

Tags: python, jinja2

Below is the code:

```
s= "Name1=Value1;Name2=Value2;Name3=Value3"
dict(item.split("=") for item in s.split(";"))
```

I would like to understand how this works. Will it perform for loop first or will it split first?

List of dictionary

```
s1= "Name1=Value1,Name2=Value2,Name3=Value3;Name1=ValueA,Name2=ValueB,Name3=ValueC"
```

Comment: It splits on ; first, otherwise it would loop over the string character by character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have python installed, I recommend using its [interactive repl](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/repl/)

With the repl you can run the parts of your program step by step:

1. s.split(";") will give you ['Name1=Value1', 'Name2=Value2', 'Name3=Value3']

```py
['Name1=Value1', 'Name2=Value2', 'Name3=Value3']
```

2. item.split("=") for item in s.split(";") will give you a [python generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that iterates on the the list from step 1 and split it off like into smaller lists like this:

```py
[['Name1', 'Value1'], ['Name2', 'Value2'], ['Name3', 'Value3']]
```

3. Finally dict(...) on the pairs will turn them into key-value pairs in a python dictionary like this:

```py
{'Name1': 'Value1', 'Name2': 'Value2', 'Name3': 'Value3'}
```

Comment: Can I know if it need split ';' first. Why the split for '=' came first. Besides that, is there issue if split '=' first. In java usually we do loop first then split but in python, it placed before the loop so was confused

Comment: I saw the for loop should have colon. But in our case didnt have colon after the for loop but it working. can i know why. I'm searching too

Comment: Good  question! This is unique Python syntax since instead of running things from left to right, it'll run them from right to left. This is called generator syntax which is used for list comprehension. I highly recommend watching this video which explains it better than I can in a comment: https://youtu.be/belS2Ek4-ow

Comment: Hi can i know is it possible to perform with list of dictionary?

Comment: What do you mean by list of dictionary? Something like this? [{'key': 'a', 'value': 'b'}, {'key': 'c', 'value': 'd'}, ...]?

Answer (score 0):

`dict` is being passed a generator expression, which produces a sequence of lists by first calling `s.split(";")`, then yielding the result of `item.split("=")` for each value in the result of the first `split`. A more verbose version:

```
s = "..."
d = dict()
name_value_pairs = s.split(";")
for item in name_value_pairs:
    name_value = item.split("=")
    d.update([name_value])
```

I use `d.update` rather than something simpler like `d[x] = y` because both `dict` and `d.update` can accept the same kind of sequence  of key/value pairs as arguments.

---

From here, we can reconstruct the original by eliminating one temporary variable at a time, from

```
s = "..."
d = dict()
for item in s.split(";"):
    name_value = item.split("=")
    d.update(name_value)
```

to

```
s = "..."
d = dict()
for item in s.split(";"):
    d.update([item.split("=")])
```

to

```
s = "..."
d = dict(item.split("=") for item in s.split(";"))
```

Comment: Can I know if it need split ';' first. Why the split for '=' came first. Besides that, is there issue if split '=' first. In java usually we do loop first then split but in python, it placed before the loop so was confused

Comment: I saw the for loop should have colon. But in our case didnt have colon after the for loop but it working. can i know why. I'm searching too

Comment: The list comprehension is not read left-to-right. The generator is evaluated first, *then* the expression on the left is executed for each element produced by the generator. The syntax of the list comprehension, though similar to a `for` loop, is *not* a `for` loop. A colon marks the "boundary" between the introduction to a compound statement and the block that makes up its body.

Answer (score 0):

If you write it like that, you might understand better what's happening.

```
s= "Name1=Value1;Name2=Value2;Name3=Value3"
semicolon_sep = s.split(";")

equal_sep = [item.split("=") for item in semicolon_sep]
a = dict(equal_sep)

print(a["Name1"])
```

First, it splits the text from wherever there is a semicolon. In this way, we create a list with three elements as "semicolon_sep":

```
>>> print(semicolon_sep)
 ['Name1=Value1', 'Name2=Value2', 'Name3=Value3']
```

Then, it makes a loop over this list to separate each item wherever there is "=". In this way, we have 2 columns for each item (Name and Value). By putting this list (equal_sep) in `dict()`  we change the list to a dictionary.

Comment: Can I know if it need split ';' first. Why the split for '=' came first. Besides that, is there issue if split '=' first. In java usually we do loop first then split but in python, it placed before the loop so was confused

Comment: I saw the for loop should have colon. But in our case didnt have colon after the for loop but it working. can i know why. I'm searching too

Comment: If you split wit "=" first, the elements become ```[["Name1],[Value1;Name2],[Value2=Name3],[Value3]]```. Then you can't make it dictionary because Value1 is assigned with Name2 and etc. For the loop, yes you can make it like java but we have the inline loop as well in python which is the one you are using.